# This code must print every other character using for loops

Tags: python, string, char

Objective: print every other character from user-inputted string in uppercase values

I inserted a slice but the code won't execute the way I want it to.

```
python
s=input("Please enter a string: ")
for char in s:
    print (char[0::2].upper())
```

If the user inputs hello, it should print:

```
H
L
O
```

Comment: You're applying the slice to every single character in turn...

Comment: `print(s[0::2].upper())`

Answer (score 1):

You've used two iteration loops; the problem calls for only one.

Your `for` loops through each character of the string.  For input "hello", it will loop five times.  `char` will take on the values `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o` in that order.

In the loop body, you've inserted an extra iteration: the string slice `[0::2]`.  First, this second iteration doesn't do anything useful for you.  Next, it's *wrong*, in that you applied it to `char`, which is a single character, not a string.

You need to apply the alternate-character slicing to the *string*, not to each of the five characters.  Alternately, you can iterate through the five characters and print only the even-numbered ones.

Slicing:

```
print(s[0::2].upper())
```

Output:

```
HLO
```

Iteration:

```
for idx, char in enumerate(s):
    if idx%2 == 0:
        print(char.upper())
```

Output:

```
H
L
O
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s=input("Please enter a string: ")
print(s[0::2].upper())
```